# Disable security rule on whm/cpanel

Tags: php, linux, server, cpanel, whm

When I am trying to upload a file via wordpress I get

```
Security Alert

The file you are uploading was rejected by the server.
It probably contents viruses or trojans that can damage your website

Do not attempt to upload it again as your IP address may be blocked.
```

I have researched and I understood is a server issue. Just that I can't contact the host, because the hosting is self-managed, so how can I make this error go away, it happens to all sites on the server. I have access to WHM and Cpanel.
I want to mention that on my localhost everything works fine, file is not infected, it's a simple image, and tested several images. I understood something that i need to white list somewhere something, but wasn't specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. it was because of plugin Pyxsoft Anti Malware & Security. Needed to login into WHM => Plugins => Pyxsoft Anti Malware => HTTP Inspector Tab => Enable http upload inspector - set to No.

Answer (score 1):

The **simple solution** to this issue is to disable ModSecurity on your Cpanel.

1. Login to your Cpanel
2. Goto the Security category and click on ModSecurity
3. Select the domain you are working with and OFF it.
4. Refresh the page

Then, you are good to go and you will be able to upload whatever file on your website.